# Why is MDC.get('transactionId') returning null in logback and Java code?

Tags: slf4j, mdc

In my project,here is logback.xml

```
    <!-- 标准 -->
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{40} %X{transactionId} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

and in java code,

```
        logger.info("get transactionId from MDC：{}", MDC.get("transactionId"));
```

but when project is running,the log print
`2023-06-01 10:59:49:979 [http-nio-8089-exec-6] INFO  c.i.o.b.s.c.u.h.biz.UnionApiBizExecutor 5305706784710656 - get transactionId from MDC：null` 
I dont konw why transactionId can't get by MDC.get("transactionId")

I want MDC.get("transactionId") effect in my code

Comment: 5305706784710656 is the transactionId, it can print by logback.xml，but can't get by java code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.